# Error calculating squared distance in Spark / Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to calculate squared distance between two features columns of a
Spark dataframe. When I run the following code

```scala
val udf_dist = funcs.udf((x:DenseVector, y:DenseVector) => Vectors.sqdist(x,y))
val df6 = df5.withColumn("dist", udf_dist(funcs.col("features"),
                         funcs.col("features2")))
```

I get error

> Name: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException
>   Message: cannot resolve
>   'UDF(features, features2)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1
>   requires vector type, however, '`features`' is of vector type.
>   argument 2 requires vector type, however, '`features2`' is of vector
>   type.

The schema of my dataframe is

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- id2: long (nullable = false)
 |-- features2: vector (nullable = true)
```

Also, the code below runs fine

```scala
val v1: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = Vectors.dense(5)
val v2: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = Vectors.dense(5)

Vectors.sqdist(v1, v2)
```

Why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark SQL after 2.0 uses by default `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector` not `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`. Also `vector` column stores `Vectors` not `DenseVectors` so you should use correct supertype:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector => MLVector, Vectors => MLVectors}

funcs.udf((x: MLVector, y: MLVector) => MLVectors.sqdist(x,y))
```

or simpler:

```scala
funcs.udf(MLVectors.sqdist _)
```